# Unity, c# how to get value of dictionary if the value is a list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Specific, I use parse, the parseobject I get from server included a key "Weapon",which is a array, and parseobject in this array .
But now I can't get access to this value, when I do this,

```
    List<ParseObject> pWeapon =(List<ParseObject>)detailObj["Maingun"];
```

the pWeapon is null,and the log is

> InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

and other convert method doesn't work either.

I add a breakpoint and as you can see ,there are values in "Maingun"

[2 values in this list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8M6X.png)

Even when I convert it to a Json,

```
    Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(detailObj["Maingun"]));
```

it return a {};

What could I do now?
Thx anyway!

Comment: This sounds like the value you're getting back in `detailObj["Maingun"]` is just null. Did you verify it actually contains a value?

Comment: @Serlite yeah, I edit these datas, so I can be sure there must be a value in detailObj["Maingun"]

Comment: if you return it to a json and it's empty, then it means it come empty from the server. you can try to convert to json the detailObj with this command `Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(detailObj))` and see the full list

Comment: @mo  detailObj can not be convert to json , the log is Parse.ParseObject
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object).....

Comment: Add another line before the line where the crash occurs: `var temp=detailObj["Maingun"];`. Put a breakpoint on the line after this one. Run the code in the debugger. When it hits this breakpoint look at the **type** of `temp` and tell us what it is.

Comment: @Richardissimo I edit again ,you can see the picture I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the screenshot of the type, it is not a `List<ParseObject>`, so the cast will fail. It is a `List<Object>`. So you need to treat it as that type, and then use Linq on that list, to create a strongly-typed list by doing this to it: `.OfType<ParseObject>()`. So you get...

```
List<ParseObject> pWeapon =
    ((List<Object>)detailObj["Maingun"]).OfType<ParseObject>().ToList();
```